# Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.Namenode

Tags: hadoop

I know this has been asked before but I could not figure out the solution. I am getting the below error when I am trying to run `hdfs name node -format`:

> Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.Namenode

[I followed the instructions from this website to install on my centos machine.](http://alanxelsys.com/hadoop-v2-single-node-installation-on-centos-6-5/) The only difference is that I installed using root instead of hadoopuser as mentioned in the link.

#### Bashrc

```sh
# User specific aliases and functions

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/usr/local/hadoop
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
```

#### hadoop-env.sh

```sh
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/
```

#### Mapred

```xml
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
</property>
```

#### Yarn-site.xml

```xml
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
```

#### core-site.xml

```xml
<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
```

#### hdfs-site.xml

```xml
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
    <value>file:///home/hadoopspace/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
    <value>file:///home/hadoopspace/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 12):

For anyone still having trouble, you need to export the `HADOOP_PREFIX` environment variable.

Add the following line to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export HADOOP_PREFIX=/path_to_hadoop_location

# for example:
# export HADOOP_PREFIX=/home/mike/hadoop-2.7.1
```

Then do `. ~/.bashrc` in your terminal and try again, this will fix the error.

Comment: There are potential other causes. This did not solve my issue, which is the same error, hadoop-2.6.3.

Comment: @KayV you should provide more details, such as: version, local installation directory, operating system, etc.

Answer (score 12):

Thanks dcsesq.

`brew` installed hadoop 2.6.0 on Mac OS 10.9.5 (maverick)

Add the following env variables to .profile `~/.bash_profile`

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.6.0
export HADOOP_PREFIX=$HADOOP_HOME/libexec
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_PREFIX
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_PREFIX
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_PREFIX
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_PREFIX
```

Source the .profile file

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Run namenode

```
hdfs namenode -format
```

Boom started, bothered me almost half a day.

Comment: Is this an answer, or a comment/reply? If the latter, I suggest pasting the code portion in a gist, and commenting with a link to such gist. Otherwise, you need to format your code (click `{ }` in editor)

Comment: Bothere me a whole day! Thank you for the env variables!

Comment: unable to resolve the issues. AFTER installation cdh5 , i am getting errors. is it any problems after installing CDH5 into the system

Answer (score 4):

Try to use the following command for formatting (no space between name and node & replace hdfs command with hadoop)

```
hadoop namenode -format
```

Comment: I tried without space and got the same error. Iam I missing anything?

Comment: Use of this script to execute namenode is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like when you execute hadoop command, not all classes (jars) are included in your classpath.
Your classpath is missing `hadoop-hdfs-<version>.jar` file.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue.

restart the terminal and try executing the command.

Terminal restart is required to make immediate effect of path variable set inside .bashrc file

Answer (score 0):

I tried the suggestions above but I still got the same error. Setting the `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` as follows in your `~/.bashrc` worked for me:

`export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$(hadoop classpath):$HADOOP_CLASSPATH`

Answer (score 0):

I had this error also. For me the problem was there were missing files that were not extracted during the initial unzipping process.

What worked for me is going into the location of your .tar.gz file and unzipping it again using:

```
tar xvzf <file_name>.tar.gz
```

Be advised this overrides all of your saved files so if you have made changes to any files, it would be best to create a copy of your Hadoop folder prior to unzipping.

Answer (score 0):

Add

> export HADOOP_PREFIX=/path/to/hadoop/installation/directory

at the end of `etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh` file in the hadoop installation directory. Which allows jvm to locate the class files.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `hdfs` path is correct by using `which`

```
which hdfs
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to missing hadoop hdfs jar files in the hadoop classpath.
Type 'hadoop classpath' in the terminal and check whether the hdfs jar files is present or not. If not paste the below line in the .bashrc and save it and source it.

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=new-classpath:$HADOOP_CLASSPATH
```

You can create the new classpath by adding the location to your hdfs jar files at the end of existing classpath and replace the section 'new-classpath' with your own.

Answer (score 0):

For Hadoop v3.1.2 on Windows 7, I had to

1. Install Cygwin (per the instructions).
2. Set the following environmental variables, noticing that those are FORWARD slashes (/) instead of BACK slashes (\):

   > ```
   > HADOOP_HOME=D:/.../hadoop-3.1.2
   >
   > JAVA_HOME=D:/.../java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201-2.b09.redhat.windows.x86_64
   > ```
3. Re-open Cygwin and CD into my hadoop directory -- must re-open to pick up the new environmental variables. Feel free to use ~/.bashrc and export HADOOP_HOME=... etc to do this too.
4. Make sure you type the following exactly:

   > `./bin/hdfs.cmd namenode -format`

   It must be .cmd or else it won't work on Windows.

After that it worked perfectly. If you're still having trouble, dig into the hdfs.cmd file and add some echo calls to print out what it's running, especially near the java call to see exactly what it is executing.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a classpath issue.

Add the following to your ~/.bashrc

```
 export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$(cygpath -pw $(hadoop classpath)):$HADOOP_CLASSPATH
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by modifying the path in .bashrc:

`export PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$PATH`

Answer (score -2):

check and set the value of `HADOOP_PREFIX` to `$HADOOP`